# A Web-based Database Simulator for students

Tags: html, mysql, database, laravel, browser

I'm tasked to work on a web based SQL simulator much like what can be found on SQL Fiddle or the one on W3Schools' SQL Tryit editor. Here are the requirements for the simulator:

- Multiple Students will be using the simulator at the same time.
- The teacher should be able to see or track their changes and queries.
- DDL should be included (e.g, CREATE, ALTER, DROP DATABASES & TABLES), of course certain privileges are enforced as to not ruin the database.

And also a simulation using MySQL directly obviously won't work. So, to anyone who has a suggestion on how to go about doing this, that would be awesome.

Comment: Have you tried anything? We aren't here to do your job...

Comment: Yes, the direct way of using MySQL, and since I figured that many users will use the database, properly tracking what the student made is difficult. What do you think? @Wernerson

Comment: @Wernerson I'm only asking for suggestions on how to go about doing it, because I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm quite a difficult task you got there...

I would try an approach like this:

- Create a sample database with some entries and tables based on the task for the students
- Whenever a students logs in and starts the task, copy this sample database for this specific user
- Create an input field for all MySQL commands in your view and an execute button
- Whenever the student clicks on execute: log his input and maybe the current database state to a log and execute the command on the database created for the user and return the return values you get from MySQL (errors, messages or selects) to the user

This approach is easy and reliable because the student can't harm another database besides his own (provided the database rights are configured correctly) and he can just restore the database from the sample database if he f*cked up.

It should also meet your requirements:

- Multiple students can work on it simultaneously: **Check**
- The teacher can track their changes: **Check**
- DDL is possible and the student can't harm anything besides his own DB: **Check**

Comment: I think I'll give this a try. But what do mean by _copy this sample database for this specific user_? As in, create a new database for the student?

And also another thing, I think this has more to do on the user privileges, on the commands and the database and its tables itself, I'm I correct?

This is really useful, man. Thank you so much @Wernerson.

Comment: Yes, what I mean with copy is make a new database for the user with the exact same tables and records in it. Then grant the user all rights for this (and only this) database. You have to create a new database user for each user of course and remember, you have to use this database user in your backend code. If you have further questions, just ask :)